# How do I remove all traces of the Cisco WebEx Connect IM program

Tags: windows-7, webex

Not sure how to as this question correctly. I had uninstalled or thought I had uninstalled the Cisco WebEx Connect program from my Windows 7 32b Professional machine. Followed the instructions to uninstall 32 bit programs from Add/Remove Programs plus followed the "How to remove all traces of an installed program in Window 7 32b Professional" instructions.

Now when I try to reinstall/install again the Cisco WebEx Connect program it says it is still installed. I search the registry for all traces of "Cisco", "webex", etc. and removed their keys. (only two were found)

What did I do incorrectly? Can you help?

Thanks

Comment: Try using [registry cleaner](https://www.piriform.com/)

Comment: Try the removal tools from [this page](https://www.webex.co.uk/support/downloads.html).

Comment: These were both somewhat helpful but not entirely.  I'm looking for something that can totally find everything in the registry that is possibly related to the Cisco WebEx Connect 7.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Cisco has a WebEx removal tool. It removed WebEx for multiple users on my Windows 10 PC. That tool is located here: https://help.webex.com/en-us/WBX000026378/Meeting-Services-Removal-Tool